# MySQLの多 対 多 テーブルから GROUP_CONCAT で、期待した組み合わせ通り結果を取得したい

Tags: mysql

**前提**
3テーブルあります

- blogテーブル。多
- tagテーブル。多
- blog_tagテーブル

tagテーブルのデータ格納例
・「tag_idカラム」2。「tagカラム」y
・「tag_idカラム」5。「tagカラム」x

---

**やりたいこと**
下記のようなデータを取得したい

```
[blog_id] => 1
[tag_id] => 2,5
[tag] => y,x
```

あるいは下記のようなデータを取得したい

```
[blog_id] => 1
[tag_id] => 5,2
[tag] => x,y
```

---

**現状**
取得結果

```
[blog_id] => 1
[tag_id] => 2,5
[tag] => x,y
```

SQL

```
SELECT
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bt.tag_id) AS tag_id,
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.tag) AS tag
FROM
 blog AS b
LEFT JOIN blog_tag AS bt ON (b.id = bt.blog_id)
LEFT JOIN tag AS t ON (t.tag_id = bt.tag_id)  
WHERE b.id = :id
```

---

**質問**
・現状のSQLで、意図した通り順番を取得できない理由は？
・やりたい取得結果を取得するSQLは？

Comment: 前提条件の話ですが、「1対多」であれば、通常は中間テーブルは必要ないはずですが、ユニーク制約などを用いて「1対多」を実現している形ですかね？それとも実は「1対多」ではなくて「多対多」を勘違いしている？

Comment: 前提条件は「1対多」ではなく「多対多」の誤りでした

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  b.id,
  group_concat(distinct t.tag_id),
  group_concat(distinct t.tag order by t.tag_id)
FROM
 blog AS b
left outer JOIN blog_tag AS bt ON (b.id = bt.blog_id)
left outer JOIN tag AS t ON (t.tag_id = bt.tag_id)
where b.id = 1;
```

とすると、意図する結果が得られると思います。

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html

上記にもありますが、 group_concat はその記法として、 order by を指定できるようになっています。そして、ドキュメントには明記されていませんが、どうやら、 distinct が付与されていた場合、暗黙的に与えられたカラムでソートしてしまう様子です。

なので、やりたいことを実現するためには、自前で order by を指定してやれば良い様子です。

これが動作する前提として、 tag.tag の名前は、ユニークである必要があります。

Comment: 「ドキュメントには明記されていませんが、どうやら、 distinct が付与されていた場合、暗黙的に与えられたカラムでソートしてしまう様子」。参考になりました。distinct外すとうまくいくので何故だろう？　もしかして「並び順には何の保証もありません」みたいな感じだろうかなと思っていました。また、group_concat にも order by を指定できるのですね。初めて知りました

Answer (score 1):

タグの名前が重複していようが、無理やり表示する別解としてこちらを残しておきます。

JSON_ARRAYAGG (5.7.22 から導入) を用いて、

```
select id, agg->'$[*][0]'  as tag_ids, agg->'$[*][1]' as tags from (
  select id, JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_ARRAY(tag_id, tag)) as agg
  from (
    select distinct b.id, t.tag_id, t.tag
    FROM
     blog AS b
    LEFT JOIN blog_tag AS bt ON (b.id = bt.blog_id)
    LEFT JOIN tag AS t ON (t.tag_id = bt.tag_id)
    where b.id = 1
  ) as t
  group by id
) as t;
```

とすることで、

```
+----+---------+------------+
| id | tag_ids | tags       |
+----+---------+------------+
|  1 | [2, 5]  | ["y", "x"] |
+----+---------+------------+
```

を得ます。

そして、自分でしたら、 json 配列を `2,5` などに整形する必要がある場合、それはアプリケーション側で実行すると思います。

---

ただ、ここまでだと tag に紐づかない blog については、

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id | tag_ids | tags   |
+----+---------+--------+
|  3 | [null]  | [null] |
+----+---------+--------+
```

が得られてしまいます。

8.0 以上の CTE を用いれば、以下のようにできます。

```
with target_id as ( select 3 ),  -- ここを実際のプレースホルダにかえる
agg as (
  select JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_ARRAY(tag_id, tag)) as agg
  from (
    select distinct b.id, t.tag_id, t.tag
    FROM
     blog AS b
    INNER JOIN blog_tag AS bt ON (b.id = bt.blog_id)
    INNER JOIN tag AS t ON (t.tag_id = bt.tag_id)
    where b.id = (select * from target_id)
  ) as t
  group by id
)
select (select * from target_id) as id,
  coalesce(
    (select agg->'$[*][0]' from agg),
    JSON_ARRAY()
  ) as tag_ids,
  coalesce(
    (select agg->'$[*][1]' from agg),
    JSON_ARRAY()
  ) as tags
```

```
+------+---------+------+
| id   | tag_ids | tags |
+------+---------+------+
|    3 | []      | []   |
+------+---------+------+
```

---

以下、手軽に検証するための CTE

```
with blog as (
  select 1 as id
  union all
  select 2 as id
  union all
  select 3 as id
), tag as (
  select 2 as tag_id, 'y' as tag
  union all
  select 5, 'x'
  union all
  select 1, 'z'
), blog_tag as (
  select 1 as blog_id, 2 as tag_id
  union all
  select 1 as blog_id, 2 as tag_id
  union all
  select 1 as blog_id, 5 as tag_id
  union all
  select 2 as blog_id, 1 as tag_id
),
-- 以下、実際のクエリ部分
target_id as ( select 3), -- ここを実際のプレースホルダにかえる
agg as (
  select JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_ARRAY(tag_id, tag)) as agg
  from (
    select distinct b.id, t.tag_id, t.tag
    FROM
     blog AS b
    INNER JOIN blog_tag AS bt ON (b.id = bt.blog_id)
    INNER JOIN tag AS t ON (t.tag_id = bt.tag_id)
    where b.id = (select * from target_id)
  ) as t
  group by id
)
select (select * from target_id) as id,
  coalesce(
    (select agg->'$[*][0]' from agg),
    JSON_ARRAY()
  ) as tag_ids,
  coalesce(
    (select agg->'$[*][1]' as tags from agg),
    JSON_ARRAY()
  ) as tags;
```

Comment: JSON_ARRAYAGG を初めて知りました。「JSON形式で返すから、group_concat使用する必要がない」という感じでしょうか？　MySQL 5.7.21なので試せませんが、5.7.22へバージョンアップデートした際には試してみたいと思います。ちなみに「->'$[*][0]」はどういう意味ですか？　キャプチャ変数？？　JSON_ARRAYAGG　とは直接関係ない？？